# Dont want to keep same record in two fields/tables in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, database-design

I have following scenario

I have news web application
I have two tables

1-**User** (Register user with news website)

2-**Comment** table and in comments table there are following some fields

```
   Comments(Comments against any news)
   userID (which user comment on agaist this news) // it is foreign key
   NewsID
   UserName(same as userID which user comment on agaist this news) varchar // this field using for non register users
```

***Scenario 1:***
    If registered users comments then I insert comments with newsid and userid 
in comments table,UserName is null in this case

***Scenario 2:***
    If non registered user(or you can say guest) comments on news then I use UserName filed not userID UserID is null in thse case

I dont want to keep record of user with two places one is in user table and second is for 
non register user scenaro in UserName field of Comments table
What you suggest

Answer (score 1):

You could manufacture unregistered users and put them in the Users table and link them with a cookie so they keep using the same information.  I think this may be similar to the way StackOverflow handles the anonymous users.

I don't see that big of a problem with your design though.  Put a constraint on the table so that exactly one of the two is NULL, and use a COALESCE in your retrieval to get a single user name in the result set:

```
SELECT COALESCE(User.UserName, Comment.UserName) AS UserName --, etc.
FROM Comment
LEFT JOIN User
    ON User.UserID = Comment.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold another table along with your other tables

- `guests` which contain a `username` and `userid` field
- `users` which contain `userid` field and other fields as you would like.

You can then cross-reference your `comments` userid column with the 2 userid columns above, to fetch the username and other information, this way you'll eliminate the need for a `username` column in `comments`

Answer (score 0):

Stay with those 2 fields in comments table. Create Anonymous user in Users table and always populate both files.
For anonymous user:
userId = Id of that single anonymous user in User table
UserName = anonymous user name

For registered user, in UserName field would be duplicated value from Users table
That would have performance benefit when displaying a news comments, as you always (I guess) need to display UserName next to the comment, but don't need user's more details immediately, so no need to join users tale in the query for the news comments.